# Multiple clients one TCP server select()

Tags: c++11, tcpserver

I'm a beginner to TCP client-server architecture. I am making a client-server application in C++ I need the server to be able to accept messages from multiple clients at once. I used [this IBM example](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=designs-example-nonblocking-io-select) as my starter for the server
server.

The client side is irrelevant but [this is my source client](https://github.com/bozkurthan/Simple-TCP-Server-Client-CPP-Example/blob/master/tcp-Client.cpp).

The problem is with the server side it allows multiple clients to connect but not asynchronously, so the server will connect with the second client after the first one finishes. I want the server to watch for messages from both clients.

I tried to read about select() on the Internet but I couldn't find anything to make the IBM code async. How can I edit the server code to allow the clients to connect and interact at the same time?

Comment: That code should accept multiple clients (at a quick glance). Select makes it async

Comment: it does accept multiple clients but it only serves one client at a time so the server maintains a queue of clients and lets them make requests one by one

Comment: Yes, it handles on tcp packet at a time. If the packets take a long time to handle you need to fire up a thread to handle them. If they are io bound, reading files the you can add those files to the select. Thats very  molex tho